# R Shiny: Click Button Within Datatable to Display Popup Twice in a row

Tags: r, datatable, popup, shiny, action-button

Using RStudio 1.0.136 and R Shiny 0.14.2, I am trying to create a data table that has an action button on each row, and when a button is clicked a popup will appear. My code is currently working, except you cannot click the same button twice in a row. I have posted 2 versions of example code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
DT::dataTableOutput("data"),

uiOutput("modal")
),

server <- function(input, output,session) {

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
   inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
 }
  inputs
}

df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
  Assessment = shinyInput(actionButton, 10, 'button_', label = "Assessment", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
  Value1 = 1:10,
  Value2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = 1:10
))

output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
  df$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
)


observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    s <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
   output$modal <- renderUI({
tagList(
bsModal(paste('model', s ,sep=''), "Assessment", "select_button", size = "small",
          textAreaInput("text", label = h3("Enter Assessment") , value = "", width = "100%", height = "200px", resize = "none"),
           actionButton("Enter", "Enter")
   ))
     })
  toggleModal(session,paste('model', s ,sep=''), toggle = "Assessment")

})      
})
```

The second code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
bsModal("modalnew", "Assessment", "select_button", size = "small",
        textAreaInput("text", label = h3("Enter Assessment") , value = "",        width = "100%", height = "200px", resize = "none"),
        actionButton("Enter", "Enter")
)

),

server <- function(input, output,session) {

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
   inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
 }
  inputs
}

df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
  Assessment = shinyInput(actionButton, 10, 'button_', label = "Assessment", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
  Value1 = 1:10,
  Value2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = 1:10
))

output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
  df$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
)

observeEvent(input$select_button, {
  s <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
  toggleModal(session, "modalnew", toggle = "close")
})   
})
```

What is entered in the popups is currently irrelevant. Any suggestions on how to allow the same button to be clicked twice in a row would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to reset the button functionality upon new selection otherwise it will 'remember' the previously clicked row. Also put your `shinyInput` outside the server it only needs to render it once

Comment: I have tried resetting input$select_button <- NULL within the observeEvent, but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there another way to reset the button functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified your code. I have used a js function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775714/5894457) link to reset the value of select_button.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)


shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(

    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    #js function to reset a button, variableName is the button name whose value we want to reset
    tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetInputValue', function(variableName){
                Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
                });
                "),
    DT::dataTableOutput("data"),

    uiOutput("modal")
  ),

  server <- function(input, output,session) {

    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
      Assessment = shinyInput(actionButton, 10, 'button_', label = "Assessment", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
      Value1 = 1:10,
      Value2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = 1:10
    ))

    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
      df$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
    )


    observeEvent(input$select_button, {
      s <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
      output$modal <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          bsModal(paste('model', s ,sep=''), "Assessment", "select_button", size = "small",
                  textAreaInput("text", label = h3("Enter Assessment") , value = "", width = "100%", height = "200px", resize = "none"),
                  actionButton("Enter", "Enter")
          ))
      })
      toggleModal(session,paste('model', s ,sep=''), toggle = "Assessment")
      ##Reset the select_button
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'resetInputValue', message =  "select_button")
    })      
  })
```

Hope it helps!