# Conditional Panel after acctionbutton clik does not work second time

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a Shiny Dashboard with different tabs and screens. The idea is that inside the Forecast tab; after clicking the "forecast details" button it apears a new screen with the forecast details. And after you can click the "back" button to go to "forecast" general screen again.

It work first time, but the second time I want to access the "forecast details" through the actionbutton it doesn't work any more; and it just displays the conditional pannel below in the same screen. Any idea about what I am missing?

Here is the ui.R

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "BLABLA",
              dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                           notificationItem(
                             text = "5 new products today",
                             icon("users")
                           ),
                           notificationItem(
                             text = "12 items reviewed",
                             icon("truck"),
                             status = "success"
                           ),
                           notificationItem(
                             text = "Data load at 86%",
                             icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                             status = "warning"
                           )
              ),
              dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "danger",
                           taskItem(value = 20, color = "aqua",
                                    "Task 1"
                           ),
                           taskItem(value = 40, color = "green",
                                    "Task 2"
                           ),
                           taskItem(value = 60, color = "yellow",
                                    "Task 3"
                           ),
                           taskItem(value = 80, color = "red",
                                    "Task 4"
                           )
              )
   ),
  dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
            menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main", icon = icon("dashboard")),
            menuItem("Forecast", tabName = "Segments", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("KPI", tabName = "KPI", icon = icon("th"))
  )
 ),
dashboardBody(
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
#First Tab
 tabItems(

  tabItem(tabName= "Main",h2("Welcome back Niek !",style="text-
   align:left;color:DarkSlateBlue ;font-size:300%; "),
          fluidPage(

            fluidRow((column(width = 12,
                             box("This app is an automated decision tool 
             that...",br(),"Brief explanation on how to use the tool",
                                 width = NULL, height = 600, solidHeader = 
       TRUE, status = "primary"
                             )
            )
            )
            )
          )
     ),

    tabItem(tabName= "Segments",
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.graph % 2 == 0 
     || input.Back % 2 !=0",
            fluidPage(
              br(),
              br(),

              fluidRow(
                box(title="Newly Promotional Items",
                    width = 3,height = 200, background = "blue",br(),
                    actionButton(inputId="graph", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                   box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")

                ),
                box(
                  title = "Promotional forecast products", width = 3,height = 200, background = "light-blue",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph2", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Products with higher number of promotions", width = 3, height = 200,background = "light-blue",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph3", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Title 6",width = 3, height = 200,background = "light-blue",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph4", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                )
              ),
              br(),

              # valueBoxes
              fluidRow(
                box(title="AX Products",
                    width = 3,height = 200, background = "purple",br(), 
                    #splitLayout(
                    actionButton(inputId="graph5", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                    box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                    #)
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Historical High Bias products", width = 3, height = 200,background = "purple",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph6", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Low FCA products", width = 3, height = 200,background = "purple",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph7", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Number of alerts",width = 3,height = 200, background = "purple",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph8", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ) 
              ),
              br(),
              fluidRow(
                box(title="Products by Segment",
                    width = 3, height = 200,background = "yellow",br(),
                    actionButton(inputId="graph9", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                    box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Products by SKU", width = 3,height = 200, background = "yellow",br(),
                  actionButton(inputId="graph10", label="Forecast Details", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
                  box(solidHeader =TRUE,"blabla",title="Product Details",align="right",height = 100, color="black")
                ) 
              ),
              verbatimTextOutput("debug")
            )
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "KPI",
          h2('KPI DASHBOARD'),br()
          #,img(src='Picture1.png', align = "right")
  )
),

conditionalPanel(
  condition= "input.graph % 2 != 0 ",
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                    box(
                      title = "Product Forecast 1", align = "center", width = NULL, height = 200, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning"
                    )
    )
    ),
    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                    box(
                      title = "Product Forecast 2", align = "center", width 
= NULL, height = 200, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning"
                    )
    )
    ),
    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                    box(
                      title = "Product Forecast 3", align = "center", width 
  = NULL, height = 200, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning"
                    )
    )
    ),
    actionButton("Back", "Back")
    )

   )
  )
)
```

And here is the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

   observe({
  if (input$graph == 0) {
  return()
 }

 })

observe({

  if (input$Back== 0) {
  return()
   }
  })
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer sorry about it! I didn't want to make pressure to anybody, it was just a way of trying to express that I am very lost with that and I would really appreciate help! Thanks for your correction!

Comment: The action button assumes random value so `input.graph % 2 != 0 ` `input.Back % 2 !=0` conditions are not correct. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775714/5894457) would help.